# Man wakes up amnesiac, potentially started a war

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia

I'm trying to find a book I read  mid 70s or so about a man who wakes up in a psychiatric hospital with no memory.

He eventually finds out that he was one of the people who started a war (possibly nuclear) in order to reduce the population.

He has nightmares about rats/mice killing one another. So I'm thinking it might be inspired by the Universe 25 experiments of John B. Calhoun.

Comment: Ooh, that sounds familiar. Wasn't it that the rats changed genetically when their population rose, making them more aggressive? In the story, I mean. I think in the end it turns out they have failed.

Comment: I reckon @SQB might be thinking of [Searching for story in which overpopulated rats kill each other](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/124893/98028), which also mentions Calhoun's experiments. Other than that, there are [some story-id questions involving rats](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D+rats+is%3Aq); might want to take a look, see if any of those rings a bell :)

Comment: @Jenayah, no, that's a different story. The one I remember — which may or may not be what DBX is looking for — involved scientists discovering that overpopulation breeding an unwanted trait into rats — could've been aggression, or insanity. To counter human overpopulation, they engineer nuclear war. In the end, there is some indication they may already be too late. I think it was a short story. I know I have it, but half my books are in storage and I'm afraid it's in that half.

Comment: Danny3414, I do not remember that in the story.

Comment: Most of the story takes place in a mental institution. The protagonist is a patient who eventually finds out that it is an artificial environment, domed or possibly underground. I don't recall which. Anyway, he finds out that he has had his memory altered/repressed and escapes. Or, escapes and then finds out about his memory.

Comment: the quiet earth by Craig Harrison?

Comment: I'll have to look at 'The Quiet Earth'. But, I don't recall that one.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 5):

This sounds very much like *[The Sun Grows Cold](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2716751-the-sun-grows-cold)* by Howard Berk, published by Dell in 1972.

[image: Book Cover - *The Sun Grows Cold*]

It opens in the Medical Division of a mostly-underground government installation called "Complex One," where large numbers of people who have gone insane for some undisclosed reason basically have their brains wiped and new personalities developed. There seems to have been some sort of war as well, but no one talks about it.

The protagonist, a "reprocessed" man given the name of Parnell, still retains enough of his old memories to try to illicitly access the Archives for all of Complex One in order to find out the reason behind its existence and the truth about the war, and escapes after being captured while trying to enter the access code.

After a long post-apocalyptic adventure, Parnell finally remembers the full access code to the Archives. He is allowed back to Complex One to learn the truth, which is that the mass insanity (called the "Compression Factor") was a genetic response to human overpopulation -- and that, in his previous life, he had been the psychologist who had discovered the Compression Factor and replicated it in rats. He had theorized that a deliberately-engineered nuclear holocaust to reduce the population could cure the resulting remnants of mankind of the insanity, and seeing his hypothetical suggestion brought to life in the form of mass destruction finally drives him around the bend.

The novel ends with him back in the Medical Division after a second treatment, content and child-like, remembering nothing of what happened.

Comment: This seems a remarkably obscure book, though I found a review on Amazon that certainly looks as if this make be the book:

Comment: Alex Parnell. A name given to a man with no memory. No memory of the holocaust which destroyed the whole world, obliterated the teeming millions, spared only a few thousand gypsies foraging up and down the few radiation free corridors where highways had once networked a nation.
The complex was safe also - a vast underground city where Alex finds himself when he emerges from treatment. Who is he? What had he been? From what intolerable burden of guilt had amnesia shielded him? Incurable insanity and savage violence guard the answer - but Alex has to know.

Comment: As I thought I might have read it the book the querant is looking for, I _do_ recognise the cover as something I've read.